# Can't load an entire csv file into a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

this is my first question here, so I hope to do it fine.

Anyway, I'm new in pyspark and I'm having some problems loading my csv file.

The thing is that I have a csv with 3 columns and around 8,000,000 rows but when I create the dataframe with pyspark and check the size of the dataframe I only get 3,124,744 with the count method.

I don't get any error message, if it wasn't  for the count verification i wouldn't notice anything wrong.

Right now I'm runing this seassion from a google colab notebook using spark-2.4.4, openjdk-8 and python-3.

```
df_ratings = spark.read.csv('rating.csv', inferSchema = True, header = True, sep = ',')
```

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Have you checked if the file is completely valid? Have you tried identifying what the last line is that does get read? What happens if you remove lines from the beginning of the file - does it read the same number of lines, or does it still stop at the same line?

Comment: try reading it as text file & check the line count. It might be because of some issue that spark is unable to read those rows

Comment: spark easily load that data. Check your file. Issue you will be in File not in spark

Comment: I checked the last line readed and nothing seems to be wrong. I tried erasing that line and the 5 lines around them but nothing happened. I also readed the file as a text file, and everything looks fine. It has ~8million rows.

Comment: have you checked the new line character of the file, are there any multi-line records in the original text file?